# Using nested ng-repeat to iterate through firebase object in Angularfire 0.8

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, firebase, angularfire

## My Goal:

I have a list that i need to iterate.  Each item in this list has a list of its own (nested).  For each of these nested list items I need to have a set of two checkboxes for the user to designate their choice.  I need to sync these checkbox choices back into the scope variable that should be synced with firebase.  **Below is a simplified version of my code.**

## Example

#### My Controller

```
fbutil.syncObject("items").$bindTo($scope, "items");
```

#### My View

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    {{item.title}}

    <div ng-repeat="option in item.options">
        {{option.title}}

        <input type="checkbox" id="{{item.title}}+{{option.title}}+pos" ng-model="option.results" ng-true-value="'positive'" ng-false-value="''"><label for="{{item.title}}+{{option.title}}+pos"></label>

        <input type="checkbox" id="{{item.title}}+{{option.title}}+neg" ng-model="option.results" ng-true-value="'negative'" ng-false-value="''"><label for="{{item.title}}+{{option.title}}+neg"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

## My Problem

I just updated from angularfire 0.7.1 to and 0.8 and started getting this error when iterating through a nested ng-repeat in my view.  it worked fine before, but now i get the error when i select a checkbox, stating:

```
Firebase.set failed: First argument  contains an invalid key ($$hashKey) in property '0.testCustom.0'.  Keys must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"
```

I understand (i think) this has something to do with Angularfire either getting the data as an array or an object. I understand that this is because angular/firebase attaches these keys (like $id or $$hashKey) to objects and using angular.copy() to clean these up does not work.

Here is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230197/how-to-save-firebase-objects-asarray-with-angularfire-when-the-objects-conta) but @kato's only reponse is not to fetch the parent but go directly to the child collection.  **I can't think of a way to do this in my situation...**
@kato's post in the comments:

> Don't fetch the parent (account/) as an object and then try and use it's child as a collection. The embedded array is not going to work since angular attaches invalid properties to it. [...] AngularFire is a bindings library--it binds objects and collections--not a local copy of your Firebase data tree. Just get the collection directly

## /////////Edit

In response to @jacobawenger's comment, how would i save these changes back to firebase if i use $asArray() instead of $asObject() to pull in my collection?

here is a plunker of what I am trying to do:

## [Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/eaFzGtMxMQ4Wa2rslDIX?p=preview)

I have a 'saveChange()' function that i do not know how to implement

Comment: As @kato was alluding to in his response on the other thread, we are moving away from using $bindTo() on deeply nested structures. It is not efficient and almost never what you actually want. Here, instead of getting the your /items/ node using $asObject(), try using $asArray(). Then you can loop over it's options and call $save() on them individually when you want to update one. This way, you are not saving your entire collection every time one option changes, which is pretty much how $bindTo() works. That simply will not scale if you have lots of items/options.

Comment: please see my edit above...

Comment: I'm not really sure where you got fbutil.syncArray from... That is not an AngularFire API you should be using. Instead, use AngularFire's $asArray() method which you can call from any $firebase object. Also, what error are you seeing this second time around? A minimized fiddle or codepen would make this significantly easier for me and would allow me to actually provide you with a fixed/working example.

Comment: oops, i didn't explain.  i am using the wrapped function from the angularfire seed app ([see on github](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire-seed/blob/master/app/js/firebase.utils.js#L12)). i'll try to come up with a plunker example

Comment: my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/eaFzGtMxMQ4Wa2rslDIX?p=preview

Comment: Sorry for the delay - super busy day today. I'm still looking into this. It looks like we may have a bug. I probably won't be able to look at it until tomorrow though.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When storing data in Firebase, it is very important to use a proper data structure. The data structure you chose is not one that works well with Firebase. You want a list of diagnoses, each with a list of tests. However, simple nesting them like you did forces Firebase to coerce them into a pseudo-array. You should be explicit about it being a list by adding each diagnosis/test via the [push() method](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/push.html). Please read [our new docs on saving lists of data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-push) to understand how to choose a good Firebase data structure. You are doing the big "ANTIPATTERN" at the top of that section which we suggest you avoid.

Using the Plunkr you provided, I went ahead and made [a new demo Firebase](https://angularfiresample.firebaseio-demo.com/) (since I couldn't see/edit your personal Firebase). I stored the data in a better data structure for Firebase. I then only had to make a few edits to your Plunkr to make [this working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/x3a690ti6eJM0y5Eef6g?p=preview). The code should be pretty self explanatory. In your view, loop through the tests for the current diagnosis and then pass the diagnosis to your `saveChange()` method:

```
<div ng-repeat="test in diagnosis.tests" class="list-group-item">
  <h4>{{test.title}} - {{test.outcome}}</h4> 

  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="test.outcome" ng-true-value="positive" ng-false-value="negative" ng-change="saveChange(diagnosis)" /> Positive

  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="test.outcome" ng-true-value="negative" ng-false-value="positive" ng-change="saveChange(diagnosis)" /> Negative
</div>
```

In your controller, just call `$save()` on `$scope.diagnoses`:

```
$scope.saveChange = function(diagnosis) {
  $scope.diagnoses.$save(diagnosis);
}
```

And that's it!

Comment: It seems the Firebase and Plunkr links are now dead. Any way you can add more of the pertinent code to your answer?